# How to apply constraint on user defined type (distinct) in Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, types

I would like to know how to apply some kind of constraint on Distinct user defined type (Object type with one attribute) in Oracle DB so that a value (price value) can't be negative number?

I have this type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE price_info AS OBJECT(
value NUMBER,
MEMBER FUNCTION get_value RETURN NUMBER)
```

Comment: Documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjdes.htm#ADOBJ00814

Comment: So I can't implement this functionality inside Object type? So how can I implement it when creating a table? How do I have to define a condition (constraint) when defining a column? In MySQL there is SIGNED or UNSIGNED if I remember... What should code look line in Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

```
SQL> create table prices
  2  (price price_info
  3  , check ( price.value >= 0));

Table created.

SQL> insert into prices values (price_info(-1));
insert into prices values (price_info(-1))
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C0012070) violated
```

Comment: This is the only way? This kind of Object type doesn't have a constructor?